# Why Doesn't Java Allow Casting Boolean -> Int?

Tags: java, types, casting

I was wondering why Java doesn't allow casting from a boolean to an int, like so:

```
boolean foo = true;
int bar = (int)foo;
```

This can be done in one line of code, for example,

```
bar = foo ? 1 : 0;
```

but it seems like an better and easier-to-read way would be to allow type-casting, as with `double` and `int`. Why doesn't Java include this feature?

Comment: Because an `int` is not a `boolean`.

Comment: What would the rules be for the casting?  Zero is false, anything else is true?  How would negative numbers be handled?  Would you be allowed to perform math?

Comment: *"Why doesn't Java include this feature?"*  One might ask why Java does not include a lot of things that could be achieved in a single code line.  I'd posit 'API bloat' as the reason.

Comment: If you really want it, you could create an int from a boolean with Apche commons BooleanUtils, e.g. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toInteger%28boolean%29.

Comment: @tstorms: or you can just, y'know, `bar = foo ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: It doesn't makes much sense...but actualy, this is not that bad question.

Comment: Casting can be dangerous if you are not doing a type check before the cast, most SDK's will not throw an error about casting but Java will.  Casting sometimes is like skipping steps in an algorithm, although you have the best intentions it can be dangerous.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It doesn't allow this because the Java designers (correctly) recognized that the boolean / integer overloading in C and C++ was a significant source of errors.

(I recall seeing that in writing in some design rationale, but I can't find it.)

For instance:

```
if (i = 0) {
    ...
}
```

is legal but probably a bug in an application that that is written C or C++.

Java avoids this and other problems by making `boolean` and the integer datatypes distinct types that cannot be converted from one to the other.  Thus, the above is a compilation error in Java.

This doesn't work in all cases.  For example (in Java):

```
if (flag = true) {
    ...
}
```

compiles.  However, it does work in enough cases to be worthwhile.  Furthermore, the *idiomatic* way to write the above in Java is:

```
if (flag) {
    ...
}
```

which avoids the pitfall entirely.  Also, a checker like `findbugs` or `pmd` should flag the incorrect version as suspicious.  (And a style checker ought to indicate that `flag == true` is bad style!)

---

Now this doesn't explain why you cannot explicitly *type cast* a `boolean` to an `int`.  But I think that can be understood by observing the following:

- You *rarely* need to do that in real Java programs.
- Number <-> boolean casting wouldn't jell with the way that other type casts work.  In particular, for other types there are up-casts and down-casts, and up-casts<sup>1</sup> in Java don't  require an explicit type cast.
- You can't typecast between numbers and string either, or between strings an other objects.  These are *conversions*, not type casts.  And `int` <-> `boolean` is too.

---

<sup>1 - I am being sloppy with my terminology here (deliberately).  The correct Java terminology is "widening" and "narrowing".  Narrowing conversions require an explicit type cast with a limited exception for literals.  Widening conversions don't require a type cast.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Java supports widening conversions on primitive numeric types. However, boolean is not considered a numeric type.

The supported widening conversions are listed under ["Widening Primitive Conversion"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) in the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 2):

Because Java is strongly typed, a `boolean` and an `int are two completely different data types`and one can not be casted to the other - it *can not* be casted, in fact.

Comment: A tautology.  You cannot cast it because it cannot be cast.