# Why is typecasting not supported for boolean in Java

Tags: java, casting, boolean

Why is boolean typecasting not supported in Java?
Why can't I perform something like this:

```
    int i = 1;
    boolean b = (boolean)i;
```

Similarly for other primitive datatypes like long,double etc.

Comment: See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281760/why-doesnt-java-allow-casting-boolean-int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `boolean` is not numeric type, while the `int`, `char`, `byte`, etc. - are.

Comment: Since everything is composed of binary values it could be said that boolean is numeric as well only it manipulates number 1 and 0. According to the link in comment this is java design.